# MySQL - Booking Query - Select All Products That Are Available In A Given Date Span

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 mysql database tables: Product & Reservation (left out unimportant columns)

Product

| Column Name | Column Type |
| --- | --- |
| product_id | INT |
| product_name | varchar |

Reservation

| Column Name | Column Type |
| --- | --- |
| reservation_id | INT |
| product_id | INT |
| start_datetime | datetime |
| end_datetime | datetime |

I am using the below query to pull available products

```
SELECT
    p.product_id,
    p.product_name
FROM
    product p
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS(
        SELECT
            *
        FROM
            reservation r
            INNER JOIN product p ON p.product_id = r.product_id
        WHERE
            AND r.start_datetime >= '2021-05-07 00:00:00'
            AND r.end_datetime <= '2021-05-07 23:59:59'
    )
```

This works mostly but the issue is that if a product is booked for more than 1 day, the product will show up.

For instance product A is booked from `2021-05-07 05:00:00 to 2021-05-08 12:00:00`. Since this product end date is out of the `AND r.end_datetime <= '2021-05-07 23:59:59'` it shows up in the query results. How can I avoid this?

Comment: Only tag with the database you are really using, which seems to be MySQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the logic you want is:

```
SELECT p.product_id, p.product_name
FROM product p
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM reservation r
                  WHERE p.product_id = r.product_id AND
                        r.end_datetime >= '2021-05-07' AND
                        r.start_datetime <= '2021-05-08'
                 );
```

This returns all produces that are not reserved for any period on 2021-05-07.

Note the changes:

- There is no `JOIN` in the subquery.  Instead, it has a correlation clause.
- The overlap logic is that the reservation ends after the day starts and that the reservation starts before the day ends.  This is general logic for an overlap.
- Times are not needed.  Plus, `<` is more accurate.

Comment: This is working perfectly. I really appreciate Gordon!